# Can we block "landscape" view on mobile on my website?

Tags: html, mobile

I would like visitors to only see the website in portrait view on a mobile so even if they flip their phones, the page won't flip.

Is that possible ?

This post below seems to ask the same thing but he want an option to switch it but I don't. Portrait view only

[How to restrict browser view to Landscape on a mobile browser in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292520/how-to-restrict-browser-view-to-landscape-on-a-mobile-browser-in-html5)

Comment: All what you want will be here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. The flipping of the page is handled natively and can't be overridden. Depending on the device you're targeting, look into responding to changes in `window.orientation`.